# Parse new User save does not return new ID

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

When saving anew user in Parse, although the user saves correctly, the new user is not returned after the save, so the code errors at `console.log("userResult id " + userResult.id);`. If the user already exists, the save function returns the id correctly. Is this a bug with Parse or am I missing something?

```
    return userQuery
        .first(function (userResult) {
            if (!helpers.isDefined(userResult)) {
                userResult = new Parse.User();
                userResult.set("username", helpers.phoneToUsername(phoneNumber));
                userResult.set("password", helpers.generatePassword(phoneNumber));
                userResult.set("displayName", displayName);
            }
            userResult.set("location", location);
            userResult.set("smsVerified", false);
            return userResult.save()
        })
        .then(function (userResult) {
            console.log("userResult id " + userResult.id); <-- ERROR HERE
            user = userResult;
            return Verification.createSmsVerification(userResult);
        })...
```

The error:

```
Result: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        userQuery.equalTo("username", helpers.phoneToUsername(phoneNumber));
```

Its as if the user is being saved after then `then()` callback, but this should not be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time fiddling around in the dark on this, I've found that the problem is the initial code is within the `first()` callback rather than the thenable. Changing the top lines of code from `first(function()...` to `first().then(function()` has solved the problem.

```
return userQuery.first()
        .then(function (userResult) {
            if (!helpers.isDefined(userResult)) {
                userResult = new Parse.User();
                userResult.set("username", helpers.phoneToUsername(phoneNumber));
                userResult.set("password", helpers.generatePassword(phoneNumber));
                userResult.set("displayName", displayName);
            }
            userResult.set("location", location);
            userResult.set("smsVerified", false);
            return userResult.save()
        })
        .then(function (userResult) {
            console.log("userResult id " + userResult.id); <-- ERROR HERE
            user = userResult;
            return Verification.createSmsVerification(userResult);
        })...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to return it:

```
  return userQuery
        .first(function (userResult) {
            if (!helpers.isDefined(userResult)) {
                userResult = new Parse.User();
                userResult.set("username", helpers.phoneToUsername(phoneNumber));
                userResult.set("password", helpers.generatePassword(phoneNumber));
                userResult.set("displayName", displayName);
            }
            userResult.set("location", location);
            userResult.set("smsVerified", false);
            return userResult.save()
        })
        .then(function (userResult) {
            console.log("userResult id " + userResult.id); <-- ERROR HERE
            user = userResult;
            return Verification.createSmsVerification(userResult);
        })...
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, well spotted. I actually took out the return to test a new scenario and forgot to put it back in. Although yours is a legitimate and correct answer! Ill update the question, I think I've also found the answer.

Comment: Not with the code you have posted. It is explained in my answer :)